# How to make Kafka consumer read from last committed offset but not from last consumed offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My requirement is simple yet not able to implement using plain consumer, I would like to consume records from Last committed offset position, every time I poll. I mean once after I polled set of records, if I am not manually committed the offset for those records, then I would expect the same set of records to be returned to me on the next poll. Is it possible to use plain Kafka consumers..? FYI I already configured my consumer, not to auto-commit.

The current workaround I employed is that I am manually seeking offset to last committed offset before every poll, but it is adding needless roundtrip and adding latency to message processing? is there an out of the box configuration available in Kafka consumer to achieve what I am expecting?

Comment: Are you not able to keep the records in memory and reprocess? Why do you need this behaviour? For retrying perhaps? Have you noticed a performance problem or are you asking if there could be one?

Comment: Kafka consumer is **very** basic (for good reason). There is little "out of the box" features other than getting records and seeking to offsets... If you're not committing, then the poll should return you the last committed offset already, not the N+1 consumed one.

Comment: @cricket_007  I guess your assumption is wrong, If we are not committing, then the poll is not returning the last committed offset, rather it is returning the N+1 consumed one. I verified the behavior already

Comment: @wobr I need this behavior to make sure I am processing the next set of a message after I processed the first set message for sure. So in my use case some time out of 10 messages on a batch, if I decided to process only the first 5 messages then I defer processing the remaining 5 of them later, so purposely I won't commit offset for those messages.

Comment: I feel like a kstreams window operation may be an option here, but that still relies on underlying API which you cannot avoid I'm afraid. If you aren't seeing an actual problem with your existing implementation, perhaps don't worry until that changes.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Still using seek?